# learning how to write complex stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, database-administration

i'm looking for good books and tutorials 
about writing complex stored procedures along with common tricks and best practices
commonly used by DBAs.

all i usually find is the basic SQL Statement tutorials ,
what i need are some good examples of Complex Data Selection 
along with common tricks of how to correctly and efficiently filter data 
for selection between multiple tables .

i release this is hard to find , because Complex DB's are usually built 
only in large projects and not for tutorials , but for the least i would like to find commonly used method applied by DBAs

thanks in advance.

Comment: an sql server DB , again i'm not looking for the regular select , join and regular sql stuff .
i'm looking for complex scenarios explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below site for download Ebook about SQL server complex stored procedure :

[1- COMPLEX STORED PROCEDURE IN SQL](http://www.ebooksdownloadfree.com/download/complex-stored-procedure-in-sql-1.html)

[2- STORED PROCEDURES](http://www.ebooksdownloadfree.com/download/stored-procedures-1.html)

[3- Google Ebook](http://books.google.com/books/about/Microsoft_SQL_Server_2005_Stored_Procedu.html?id=qf7Wuhnq3ZQC)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of site but I find [This site](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/author/pinaldave/) is very helpful for my SQL Server learning. It is very informative site for database developers. If you want to read books then probably you can pick on from Microsoft press.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [The Guru's Guide To Transact SQL by Ken Henderson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615762), a bit old, but probably still the best book about T-SQL :)